# Prove partial differentiation equation

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $z=f(x, y), x = r \cos \theta,  y = r \sin \theta$,  prove the equation below

$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right) ^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right) ^2 =\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \right) ^2 +\left(\frac{1}{r} \right) ^2\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} \right) ^2$

This is a calculus problem in $R^n \mapsto R$. I tried it by using chain rule but found nothing.  Also, I substitute $z, x, y$ in the left side of the equation,  hoping to get the right one,  but I can't proceed somehow. 
Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}  + \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} $$ $$= \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \frac{1}{\cos \theta} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} \frac1{r \sin \theta} $$

Similarly can you solve the other one as well?